# Seaborn lineplot high cpu; very slow compared to matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, performance, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe.

```
In [12]: dfFinal
Out[12]: 
           module                                            vectime                                           vecvalue
1906  client1.tcp  [1.1007512, 1.1015024, 1.1022536, 1.1030048, 1...  [0.0007512, 0.0007512, 0.0007512, 0.0007512, 0...
1912  client2.tcp  [1.10079784, 1.10159568, 1.10239352, 1.1031913...  [0.00079784, 0.00079784, 0.00079784, 0.0007978...
1918  client3.tcp  [1.10084448, 1.10168896, 1.10258008, 1.1036111...  [0.00084448, 0.00084448, 0.00089112, 0.0010310...
```

I want to plot the timeSeries `vecvalue` vs `vectime` for each module.

The result is the following:
[image]

To do so I can do as follows:

1) Matplotlib

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()

for row in dfFinal.itertuples():
    t = row.vectime
    x = row.vecvalue
    x = runningAvg(x)
    plot(t,x)

total = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
print("Total time: ",total)
```

Doing so, takes `0.07005` seconds to accomplish.

2) Seaborn

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()

for row in dfFinal.itertuples():
    t = row.vectime
    x = row.vecvalue
    x = runningAvg(x)
    DF = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 't':t})
    sns.lineplot(x='t', y='x', data=DF)

total = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
print("Total time: ",total)
```

Doing so, takes `19.157463` seconds to accomplish.

Why is there such a huge difference? What is it that I'm doing so wrong that it takes that long to process a rather small DF?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have 1 million data points, matplot lib plots almost instantly, while seaborn takes a forever.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Set `ci=None` in the call to `lineplot`; otherwise, confidence intervals will be computed resulting in some expensive (and unnecessary) `df.groupby` calls.

An aside: the `snakeviz` module is a great tool for quickly finding computational bottlenecks.

Comment: Awesome! Helped me so much!

Comment: for `seaborn>=0.12.0`: `estimator=None` and `n_boot=0`